# Change background color back jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net

I am writing a webpage and this webpage have a menu that changes its background color while been clicked. I am doing this with jquery. Right now I am just working on the menu itself. However I encountered a problem. My menu item which is in a list does change color after I click on it. But after I click another button I want the previous change to go away without causing a postback. does anyone have a good idea how to do so?

here is my code

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>

    <link href="Content/TreeViewCss.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="tree well">
    <ul>
        <li style="width: 100%">
            <span ><i class="icon-folder-open"></i>Parent</span>
            <ul style="width: 100%">
                <li>
                    <span><i class="icon-minus-sign"></i>Child</span>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <span><i class="icon-leaf"></i>Grand Child</span>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <span><i class="icon-minus-sign"></i>Child</span>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <span><i class="icon-leaf"></i>Grand Child</span>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <span><i class="icon-minus-sign"></i>Grand Child</span>
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <span><i class="icon-minus-sign"></i>Great Grand Child</span>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>
                                            <span><i class="icon-leaf"></i>Great great Grand Child</span>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <span><i class="icon-leaf"></i>Great great Grand Child</span>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <span><i class="icon-leaf"></i>Great Grand Child</span>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <span><i class="icon-leaf"></i>Great Grand Child</span>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <span><i class="icon-leaf"></i>Grand Child</span>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <span><i class="icon-folder-open"></i>Parent2</span>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <span><i class="icon-leaf"></i>Child</span>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

</div>
</form>
```

and the jquery script to change color

```
    <script>
    $("span").click(function () {

        $(this).css("background-color", "gray");
    });
</script>
```

I am using asp.net webforms and all the jquery libraries are included already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rather add class with CSS and then toggle it using `addClass()` and `removeClass()`:

**For Adding and Removing Class:**

```
 $("span").click(function () {
   $("span").removeClass("greybg");
   $(this).addClass("greybg");
 });
```

**CSS:**

```
.greybg{background-color:gray}
```

Comment: Does it mean that when you do removeclass("greybg") it removes the css "greybg" on ALL the span?

Comment: @user2948725: yes it will. or other wise you need to modify selector to target only required span/spans .

Comment: This does not fix my problem. I understand what you are doing here but the problem is I need to REMOVE the css applied to the prvious span after I click another span. in this case it does not remove the previous background. I want to first take off the previous background color applied to another span. Then apply the css to the current span

Comment: never mind MY BAD I forgot a bracket sorry about that

Comment: Can I ask another thing while we are at it? Now why when I apply the same tick to the list itself: ie when clicking on the list and the list changes background color this way I do not have to collapse or expand the row itself. but only highlight the row that I am selected.
But when I am trying to apply this by doing 
    $("li").click(function () {
            $('li').removeClass("greybg");
            $(this).addClass("greybg");

The Whole entire list turns grey. I mean including its parent is it something on the list property that is causing this?

Comment: @user2948725: yup. if its related to this.

Comment: I edited my previous reply to add in the question sorry about inconvenience

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60630/discussion-between-milind-anantwar-and-user2948725).

Comment: basically when I tried to apply the jquery to the list it changes the whole list including its parent even when I am just clicking on the child. What is the cause of this? I want to only highlight the child list. but parent gets changed as well

Comment: @user2948725: you need to modify the CSS in that case. Can you post a fiddle. can help with that.

Comment: Here I posted it in JS fiddle and what I want to do is when I click on the space in the row that is NOT on the span the row gets high lighted but when I do it in this case it doesn't work. even when I click on the sub rows the parent gets highlighted too http://jsfiddle.net/shv8a7qy/2/

Answer (score 0):

The easiest, fastest, and best way to do this is to leverage CSS and just add / remove a class.

```
.BackgroundGray {
    background-color:gray
}
```

Then add the class in jQuery:

```
$(this).addClass('ButtonGray');
```

Then remove the class later with some other event:

```
$(this).removeClass('ButtonGray');
```

Simple, clean, and extensible.

Answer (score 0):

Just use this

**JavaScript**

```
$("span").click(function () { // use selector as per your requirement instead of span may be some class
   $('.greybgByJs').removeClass("greybgByJs");
   $(this).addClass("greybgByJs");
});
```

**Css**

```
.greybgByJs{background-color:gray}
```

This way only the last clicked element will have Gray background